# Azure Function Permission Denied - When calling function from installed package (dbt)

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions, dbt

I've attempted to create an Azure Function to run dbt (data build tool), although can't get the Function to work when deployed (works fine locally), as getting a permissions error.

Overview of Az Function set-up:

- OS – Linux
- Publishing as Code, not Docker – is this an issue?
- Plan - Functions Premium EP1
- Python 3.9
- dbt-core==1.3.0 added to requirements.txt
- Testing via Azure portal Function 'Code + Test'

At this stage I'd just like the dbt helper text to appear in the `logging.info` output as test that `dbt` can be called.

`__init.py__` contains the following:

```
import logging
import subprocess

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    logging.info('Start With Popen dbt')
    #with subprocess.Popen(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) as proc: # this runs fine, although shell cmd shell=True 
    with subprocess.Popen(["/tmp", "dbt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc: # Attempt to output dbt helper as doesn't write to log- When running locally subprocess.Popen(["dbt"] remove "/tmp"
        for line in proc.stdout:
            line = line.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '').strip()
            logging.info(line)
    logging.info('End With Popen dbt')
```

Error message:

```
Result: Failure Exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:'/tmp' Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", 
line 458, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", 
line 58, in run result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", 
line 701, in _run_sync_func return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/extension.py", 
line 215, in _raw_invocation_wrapper result = function(**args) File "/home/site/wwwroot/HttpTrigger_dbt/__init__.py", 
line 11, in main with subprocess.Popen(["/tmp", "dbt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc: # Attempt to output dbt helper as doesn't write to log- When running locally remove subprocess.Popen(["dbt"] remove "/tmp" File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", 
line 951, in __init__ self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", 
line 1821, in _execute_child raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

Within `__init.py__` running `ls` instead of `dbt` works fine, although this is a shell cmd as opposed to a function from an installed package.

I've seen setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0` mentioned when investigating the issue and also had a response to the following [MS Q&A Post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1160395/azure-function-permissionerror-(errno-13)-permissi) suggesting that - Although when setting to 0 I can't seem to redeploy.

I have confirmed the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` has not been set; by not set there is no setting associated `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` as opposed to 0/1, by looking at:

- `Azure > Function App > Advanced Tool  - Environment > AppSettings`
- `zure \> Function App \> Configuration \> App Setting`
- `VS Code \> Function App \> App Setting`

I'm unsure as what the issue is, either:

- I can't achieve what I want by running dbt in an Az Fucntion as calling a function from a package.
- I'm missing something from my set-up/config
- `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = 0` should work and I have a seperate deployemnt issue?
- I need to publish as Docker instead of Code?

I've created the following test repo if required for reference: [azfunc-dbt-test](https://github.com/MarkrJames/azfunc-dbt-test)  - the bicep file contains the Function Config settings, although will not work if you attempt to deploy - still trying to get to grips with Bicep.

Any help or suggestions with this issue would be much appreciated.

**Update**

One thing I've noticed within `Azure Portal > Function App > Development Tools > SSH` If I run `pip list` dbt does not appear, only the following:

```
pip        22.0.4
ptvsd      4.3.2
setuptools 58.1.0
wheel      0.38.4
```

Next I ran `find -name "*dbt*"` Files of interest are:

```
./site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/bin/dbt
./site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/dbt
./site/wwwroot/logs/dbt.log
```

Running:
`dbt` results in `-bash: dbt: command not found`
`pip install dbt-core` then `dbt` results in the dbt helper text as expected

This seems to install dbt into a different location:

```
find -name "*dbt*"
/usr/local/bin/dbt
./usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dbt
```

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(["/tmp", "dbt"])` is similar to typing `/tmp dbt` at your shell. The error is saying you can't execute the `/tmp` directory. If dbt is installed (globally or in an active venv), you should just be able to `subprocess.Popen(["dbt"], shell=True)`, or use the preferred `subprocess.run(["dbt"], shell=True)`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of pain and trial and error(!!!) I went down the Azure Function Publish as **Docker** route, as opposed to **Code** as was my original attempt.

I then set up an Azure DevOps Pipeline.

Within the Pipeline script `azure-pipelines.yml` I noticed that a target path was being set for `pip install`  - `pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages"` - I assume this is also the publish as Code default setting.

```
- bash: |
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
```

Removing the target path for `pip install` solved my issue and allowed me to run the dbt package, assume the same result for any additional packages installed.

```
- bash: |
    pip install -r ./requirements.txt
  workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
  displayName: 'Install application dependencies'
```

I assume the issue is that the dbt package could not be accessed in the default installation location.

I'm unsure if the default `pip install` path can be altered when publishing an Azure Function as Code - Hopefully someone can respond to this.